# PMD - Check code error

Tags: java, eclipse, pmd

I've installed PMD plugin & enabled the option to use custom ruleset in project's PMD properties.

But when I click on `Check Code`, I get below error:

> `An internal error occurred during: "ReviewCode".`
>   `Couldn't find the class Can't find resource rulesets/typeresolution.xml.  Make sure the resource is a valid file or URL and is on the CLASSPATH. Here's the current classpath: D:\eclipse\plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.0.v20130327-1440.jar`

Comment: Is this custom ruleset old? PMD 4 and 5 aren't compatible

Comment: seems.. I tried to create the new ruleset xml, based on the current ruleset & it again said 'not supported'

Comment: can you share the settings you have placed?